# Electric potential and image charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, method-of-images

I am trying to understand how to find the electric potential around a system of a point charge of -Q and a spherical conductor charged with Q placed at a distance of L from it.

[image]

I know that for a similar problem, where the sphere is grounded the problem could be solved using an image charge inside the sphere.

I've tried using the same method for this problem, but couldn't understand how does the surface charge on the sphere affect the surface condition of this problem.

I assume that the charge inside the sphere will split according to the distance from the point charge but couldn't find the appropriate image charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find the potential of the sphere without using the method of images. Since the sphere is a conductor, so the value of net electric field inside the sphere is zero, which readily implies that the potential at the center of the sphere is equal to the potential at the surface of the sphere, since there's no net electric field acting when you move from the center to the surface. So now, we will have to find the potential at the center. Now notice that no matter how you arrange/distribute the $+Q$ charge on the sphere, all the charged elements will always be at an equal distance from the center, and thus the potential due to the sphere will be

$$V_{\text{sphere}}=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \oint \frac{\mathrm d q}{R}=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R}$$

And the potential due to the charge is simply

$$V_{\text{charge}}=\frac{-Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 L}$$

Thus the net potential will be the sum of these two potentials

$$V_{\text{net}}=V_{\text{sphere}}+V_{\text{charge}}$$

which can be easily found.